# how to get length of a textbox value which is undefined due to ng-pattern restriction in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to calculate length of textbox on button click and implement some other functionality depends on length returned. 
In normal angularjs code flow, i'm able to get result.

But when I restrict the textbox and `ng-pattern="/^([0-9]{1,25})?$/"`, and just try to get length on entering alphabets, I`m getting:

> length undefined

I cannot expect user understand to enter only numbers at first input entry. Hence even on entering alphabets, how to get length of input without removing ng-pattern or any other alternate way.

Here is the code.

Comment: how your trying to get the length??have u tried with ng-change??

Comment: No. I`m trying on ng-blur. Earlier tried with ng-change, but getting undefined due to ng-pattern accepts only numbers..

Comment: Why not set the input to type="number" and do away with the need for ng-pattern altogether?

Comment: yah. but in another input it is alphanumeric but not special characters. have to take length of each input. So prefered to proceed this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this is your requirement

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope ){
  $scope.len=0;
 $scope.call=function(x){
   $scope.len=x.length;
 }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <input type="text" ng-pattern="/^([0-9]{1,25})?$/" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}" ng-model="called" ng-change="call(called)">
  
  <p>length={{len}}</p></body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is very much useful. Adding ( ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}" ) solved the issue.